# duplicate android:theme androidmanifest

Tags: android

i embedding a code that contains one android:theme with my original code that also have one android:theme, is it possible to have 2 android:theme

I dont now any other way to have this 2 styles.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme_1" />
<activity android:name="xxxxxxxxx.RegisterActivity"></activity>
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme_1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: In your manifest you're declaring your app's theme, you don't list all the available themes. So essentially in your manifest just mention your default one, and then in your styles you can include as many themes as you want. You can then proceed to apply them programmatically at runtime.

Comment: so in manifest i only have 1 android:theme="@style/AppTheme",  and in style i can have  style name="AppTheme" and  style name="AppTheme_1".

Comment: nobody that can help me, im new in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it in this way (having 2 android:theme).

Depending on your requirements, there can be other ways to achieves.

For example, for most of your screen you want to use your own theme and for certain Activity you want this AppTheme_1, you can try this in that Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have many themes for same app

but, I suggest do it programmatically using `setTheme()` method.

with that method, you  can replace your themes as you need depending on your needs

you can learn more about themes and styles from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes?authuser=1)